# django - on model save method, determine if field value is set explicitly, or a default value is being used

Tags: python, django, django-models

With following model;

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='default_value')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field is not None # True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field is not None # True

MyModel.objects.save(a=1, b=2) # Not setting my_field here
```

Here, in the two methods above (or somewhere else), is there a way to determine of my_field value was set expliclitly, or the model is using the default value here? Checks return True when I don't set a value explicitly for the model field, and has 'default_value' value.

EDIT

To better exemplify, I want to be able to differentiate between these 2 cases:

```
MyModel.objects.save(a=1, b=2) # not seting a value for my_field
MyModel.objects.save(a=1, b=2, my_field='default_value') # setting to default value explicitly
```

Comment: isn't `self.my_field == "default_value"` enough?

Comment: but I want to differentiate between the cases when someone set the default value explicitly, and not set any value at all. This check would return True in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how I can do this, its quite simple actually, but did not occur to me when I first tried. If I'm not missing an edge case or sth, we can check the kwargs on **init** method for this purpose, like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='default_value')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field_supplied = 'my_field' in kwargs # True if my_field provided explicitly, false otherwise
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.my_field_supplied: # Can read the attribute we set on __init__ method here
            pass

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```